# Lubridate: expand minutes output to have a length of 3

Tags: r, lubridate

What I'm trying to do is get lubridate to make the minute portion of the conversion always have a length of 3. This is so that further processing is of a uniform length. E.g the time 12:00 is converted to 12H 00M 0S instead of the default output of 12H 0M 0S. I can't see anything in the help for hm() so it may be necessary to use something outside of the lubridate package.

Below is some sample code of this idea:

```
library (lubridate)
df <- data.frame("Time" = c("13:04", "13:55", "8:00", "8:45"))
df$Time <- hm(df$Time)

# Desired output
# 13H 04M 0S
# 13H 55M 0S
# 8H 00M 0S
# 8H 45M 0S
```

Comment: Is the M necessary? `as.character(strptime(df$Time, "%H:%M"), "%H %M %S")` returns the time as 13 04 00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will get your desired output:

```
library (lubridate)
df <- data.frame("Time" = c("13:04", "13:55", "8:00", "8:45"))

paste0(hour(hm(df$Time)), "H ", sprintf("%02d", minute(hm(df$Time))), "M 0S")
"13H 04M 0S" "13H 55M 0S" "8H 00M 0S"  "8H 45M 0S"
```

However, I don't know what kind of "further processing" you aim to do, but this format won't allow for subsequent time/numeric computations.

```
hour(hm(df$Time)) #gives the hours
minute(hm(df$Time)) #gives the minutes
sprintf("%02d", ...argument2...) # forces the 2nd argument call (here the minutes) of that function to consist of 2 characters, which adds the zeroes when needed 
paste0() #pastes the hours and minutes together as 1 string, with the string "H " inbetween and the string "M 0S" at the end
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain how this is working? My reason for using this way is I'm importing a file from excel where the time is stored in a really weird format that R doesn't import as serial time. This data is then being manipulated as a character and then changed into a numeric to be used later on in a very simple setting. Hence the need to not use store this in a  POSIX style.

Comment: Sure, I'll add above in the answer for clarity.